# How to tell if MediaPlayer is playing?

Tags: java, arm, javafx-2, mp3, audio-player

How can I tell if javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer is playing? Preferably without any external imports or additions to the build path. If this is not possible, are there any libraries that I can use that are self-contained?  I am installing this software on an ARM CPU so I am trying to make this code as minimalist as possible. I am only going to use this framework to play music files and primarily MP3s. Any suggestions on how I can tell if the player is playing music with this or a different library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if I understood:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        playing = false;
    }
});

mediaPlayer.setOnReady(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mediaPlayer.play();
        playing = true;
    }
});
```

Or

```
boolean playing = mediaPlayer.getStatus().equals(Status.PLAYING);
```

Comment: The thing I would like to point out though is that the second method requires an import while the first one does not. The first one works perfectly though. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but for the boolean it is :  Status.READY