# How to check if external media player is playing in android?

Tags: android, media-player

I want to stop my media player if external media player is playing.

I've implemented following code but it is called even when my app media player is playing.

```
if (audioManager.isMusicActive()) {
                    return;
                }
```

How to distinguish between in-app media player and external media player?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please go through to this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/18343457/5308778](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18343457/5308778)

Comment: @LakshayJuneja - There is no such method mediaPlayer.getStatus().

Comment: You can try this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/28805205/5308778](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28805205/5308778)

Answer (score 0):

> Two or more Android apps can play audio to the same output stream
>   simultaneously. The system mixes everything together. While this is
>   technically impressive, it can be very aggravating to a user. To avoid
>   every music app playing at the same time, Android introduces the idea
>   of audio focus. Only one app can hold audio focus at a time.

Further,

> A well-behaved audio app should manage audio focus according to these
>   general guidelines:
>
> Call requestAudioFocus() immediately before starting to play and
>   verify that the call returns AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED. If you design
>   your app as we describe in this guide, the call to requestAudioFocus()
>   should be made in the onPlay() callback of your media session. When
>   another app gains audio focus, stop or pause playing, or duck the
>   volume down. When playback stops, abandon audio focus. Audio focus is
>   handled differently depending on the the version of Android that is
>   running:

You can check the more detail from developer [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus.html).